# Mass-spring system on an incline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image: block-spring system]

I am reviewing for an exam next week, and this is one of the questions I am stuck on. I have the mass-spring system above with spring constant $k$ on a frictionless incline. I would like to find the total energy of the system at any time $t$.

I know that the total energy of the system is going to be the sum $E = K + U_g + U_s $

My first question is that I am confused about how to approach the problem. If  I take my axes along the ramp, then the problem becomes one dimensional. My idea was set up my coordinate system like that so I could describe the displacement of the mass around it's equilibrium position on the ramp so I could find $K + U_s$, and then switch back to a more traditional coordinate system where I take my axes along the perpendicular sides of the ramp to find $U_g$. Does this approach work? If not what should I be doing?

Comment: You can just stay on the inclined coordinates. $U_g$ is found by the projection of gravity along the motion axis.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with a single coordinate system - along the ramp. Vertical displacement (needed to express $U_g$) can be expressed in terms of the displacement from equilibrium along the ramp $s$ and the angle $\theta$: $y = s \sin\theta$.

So the total energy is $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - mgs \sin\theta + \frac{1}{2}ks^2$

Comment: This is more or less what I meant,I apologize if it was not clear.

The other part that has me confused is how to find the correct equation of motion. Suppose I displace the block from its equilibrium position by some amount $x_0$ and release it from rest. Then I believe my equation of motion is  $m \ddot{x}+kx = 0$ with $x(0) = x_0$, $\dot{x} = 0$. If I use newton's laws I have that $F_{net} = m\ddot{x} = mg\sin(\theta) - kx$. Which of these should I use? If I use the right initial conditons will both give me the same thing?

Comment: @user30488 your first equation is not correct, however your last one is, so the differential equation is $m\ddot{x}+kx=mg\sin{\theta}$. Which should give a cosine around the equilibrium position with an angular velocity of $\omega=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$.